# ASP.NET Code Access Security - System.Net.SocketPermission

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email

I am working in ASP.net 4.0 and this program is designed to read an email off the pop3.mail.com server.

Error Code:

> Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.SocketPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Other email programs like Pop3Client and OpenPop.dll do not work with ASP.net 4.0.

This program may work in 4.0 because there are no external dll programs attached to it.

Code:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim tcpclient As New TcpClient()
        tcpclient.Connect("pop3.mail.com", 995)
        Dim sslstream As System.Net.Security.SslStream = New SslStream(tcpclient.GetStream())
        sslstream.AuthenticateAsClient("pop3.mail.com")
        Dim sw As System.IO.StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(sslstream)
        Dim reader As System.IO.StreamReader = New StreamReader(sslstream)
        sw.WriteLine("USER email@mail.com")
        sw.Flush()
        sw.WriteLine("PASS pass1")
        sw.Flush()
        sw.WriteLine("RETR 1")
        sw.Flush()
        sw.WriteLine("Quit ")
        sw.Flush()
        Dim str As String = String.Empty
        Dim strTemp As String = String.Empty
        While ((strTemp = reader.ReadLine()) <> "")
            If strTemp = "." Then
                Exit While
            End If
            If strTemp.IndexOf("-ERR") <> -1 Then
                Exit While
            End If
            str = str & " " & strTemp
        End While
        TextBox1.Text = str
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: This lib works for me https://github.com/smiley22/S22.Pop3

Answer (score 2):

> Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.SocketPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

I'll *assume* this is related to usage in ASP.Net context. If so,

- If this is on a *shared* hosting environment, it's *likely* (check) that your hosting provider will have ASP.Net trust level set to `medium trust`
- while doing dev, on your local machine, you're doing so in `full trust`. If you [set your ASP.Net locally to `medium trust`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/tkscy493%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), you should be able to reproduce the error in your local dev environment to confirm.

This difference matters. Refer to [this MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87x8e4d1.aspx) - the table will be helpful. You will see that `System.Net.SocketPermission` in `Medium Trust` has **No permission**.

Hth...